# Difference between group key agreement, group key sharing, group key distribution and group key establishement

Tags: diffie-hellman, secret-sharing, key-distribution

I am currently doing a survey on group key, and throughout my readings, I stumbled on these different terms: **Group Key agreement, Group key Sharing, Group key distribution, and Group key establishment**.

My question is the following: is there a meaningful difference between those different terms? because what I know is at the end, all members in the group should have the same key.

Comment: I think there used to be a minor note from some people in that for "agreement" all involved parties should be able to influence the key. I don't think this distinction is made anymore though.